# foreman UI puppet run fails 500

Tags: puppet, theforeman

when click on ‘run puppet' at host web,an error appeard like this:

Error: 执行 puppetrun 失败：ERF12-4252 [ProxyAPI::ProxyException]: 无法执行 Puppet 运行 ([RestClient::InternalServerError]: 500 Internal Server Error) 代理服务器 https://ppt.YLY:8443/puppet

it means :
Error: Executing puppetrun failed: ERF12-4252 [ProxyAPI :: ProxyException]: Unable to perform Puppet run ([RestClient :: InternalServerError]: 500 Internal Server Error) Proxy: https: //ppt.YLY: 8443 / puppet

and logs in /var/log/foreman/ show the same error,nothing additional.
have someone saw this?
thx in advance.

Comment: The error comes from the smart proxy. Check /var/log/foreman-proxy/proxy.log for more information, and share your smart proxy's puppet.yml configuration.

Comment: it solved by decrease the version of foreman.thx all the same.

Answer (score 0):

it solved by decrease the version of foreman